# Nested ScrollViews and GeometryReader

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm trying to make an horizontal scrollable component (HScroll) inside a vertical scrollable one(something like the AppStore screen but with more constraints). The constraints are:

- Inside the HScroll the item width is relative to its parent width (parent width - X)
- The item inside the HScroll has a dynamic height so the HScroll should have a dynamic height

This is a code sample on how I'm trying to implement it (inside the vertical ScrollView there is other components)

```
ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
    GeometryReader { geo in
        ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
            HStack {
                ForEach(cards) { card in
                    HStack(alignment: .center) {
                        card.image
                        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                            Text(card.title)
                            Text(card.description)
                        }
                    }.frame(width: geo.size.width - 32)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My problem here is if I'm using the `GeometryReader` then the HScroll will always be cropped vertically and if I add `scaleToFill()` or `scaleToFit()` to the `GeometryReader` it will get a height higher than needed (height will be equal to width). If I don't use the `GeometryReader` I will not get the item needed width (it will fit its content).

If there is any other way to get the parent width without using `GeometryReader` or to resize a child item relative to it's parent it will be helpful also.

Comment: your `.frame(width: geo.size.width - 32)` modifier seems attached to a wrong thing. Did you mean to add it to `HStack` under `ForEach` rather?

Comment: Also what `ScrollView(.vertical` is supposed to accomplish? is it so that image larger than screen has a scroll?

Comment: Yes the `.frame` is under the `HStack` and not `ForEach`. No the image is a small one (46x46). The weird thing is that the `GeometryReader` has always 10 as height value if I am not using `scaleToFill` or `scaleToFit`.